# Determine missing number in the following sequence of odd number - 1,3,7,9,11,13

Tags: mysql

```
Table: Sequence

id
1
3
7
9
11
13
```

What I tried is  :

```
select l.id + 1 as start
from sequence as l
left outer join sequence as r on l.id + 1 = r.id
where r.id is NULL;
```

This does not capture all required numbers but only the +1s from the number available in the initial table.
My required output is :

```
2
4
5
6
8
10
12
```

Comment: do you only want missing numbers that are between the lowest and highest ones that exist?  in your example, if 1 or 13 are missing do you want them as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a calendar table approach:

```sql
WITH nums AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL
    SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
)

SELECT n.id
FROM nums n
LEFT JOIN Sequence s
    ON s.id = n.id
WHERE
    s.id IS NULL;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, which don't support CTE, you may either create a bona fide `nums` sequence table, or just inline the CTE:

```sql
SELECT n.id
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12 UNION ALL
    SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL SELECT 15
) n
LEFT JOIN Sequence s
    ON s.id = n.id
WHERE
    s.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I tried above but it failed with : 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'nums AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL
   ' at line 1

Comment: @SweetyP It looks like you're probably still on MySQL 5.7 or earlier.  Please upgrade at your earliest convenience.  I have given you a workaround in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks Tim, is there any other way of displaying missing values except UNION ? As what if the series go to 1000?

Comment: @SweetyP Then you should, as I suggested above, look into creating a sequence table.  There are plenty of questions/answers on this site which show you how to do that.  I only have given you the logic for how to use such a table, not how to create it.